# Heroku facebook login "One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings."

Tags: facebook, heroku, authentication

I'm developing with Heroku server to study the FaceBook API. I developed some code and i could login and show the content from API "/me/home" via Php Sdk.
...but now my app is not able to login, this happened out of nowhere, it gives the message

"*One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains*"....

My app is here: http://radiant-retreat-4216.herokuapp.com/facebookfeeds/
In the facebook config page i have: Hosting URL: https://radiant-retreat-4216.herokuapp.com/
(it is populated by default when you create a Heroku app)

There is nothing in "App Domains" field.

I think there is a problem with my php sdk because the JavaScript can verify the login and shows the user loggedin information.

could you help me?